# Instance field access outside constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

I am programming a flutter app and have written dart class.

When I call the classes constructor, I the following error at runtime...

```
 error: Instance field access outside constructor
```

The class looks as follows...

```
import '../framework/server.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class GamesRequestMessage extends Message {

    String getName() => "GamesRequestMessage";

    String idToken;

    GamesRequestMessage({ @required this.idToken = idToken });

    JsonObject content()
    {
        JsonObject content = JsonObject();
        content.writeString("idToken" , idToken);
    }
}
```

And the calling code where the error occurs is as follows...

```
var msg = GamesRequestMessage (idToken : idToken.token);
```

What has gone wrong? Also, why is this error not a compilation time error?

Answer (score 0):

`this.idToken = idToken` should be just `this.idToken`

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this code is valid though, and not a compilation error?

Comment: I don't know for sure why it compiles. I'm guessing `this.idToken = idToken` is the same as `this.idToken = this.idToken`. Maybe so you can write something like `this.idToken = this.defaultIdToken`. ‍♂️